# Classification of Open Subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, cardinals

Is there some nice-ish characterization of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$? For example, open subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ can be represented as the countable union of disjoint open intervals, so they can be mapped to sequences $(a_1,b_1,a_2,b_2,...)$ in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\pm\infty\}$. It seems like it would be far more complicated for the 2 dimensional case, but is there some other way to describe each open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ using a sequence of numbers as in the 1 dimensional case?

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how to associate a sequence as you say. The set $U = \mathbb{R}\setminus(\{0\}\cup \{\pm 1/n \; | \; n=1,2,\dots\})$ is open. Which sequence corresponds to $U$?

Comment: @Albert My bad, they wouldn’t be increasing, only $a_i<b_i$

Comment: What about $\Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$? Are $a_i$ and $b_i$ real numbers?

Comment: @MilesGould I still can't figure the sequence to the open set $U$ I proposed

Comment: @jjagmath No they can be $\infty$, I just fixed it.

Comment: @Albert For that set you could take $(-\infty,-1,1,\infty, -1,-\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{1}{2},1,-\tfrac{1}{2},-\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{2},\ldots)$

Comment: @jjagmath Thank you for adding the $\pm$. I’m on my phone so I’m not very Latex dexterous.

Comment: The reason why open sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are so nice is because $\mathbb{R}$ is locally connected, and a connected open set is always an open interval. There is no such characterization in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Even if we study connected open sets alone, they can be of various shapes, from something like $\{x : a < |x| < b\}$ which has a hole in the middle, to something like $\{x : a < |x| < b, x_2 < 0\}$ which has no holes but still looks quite exotic.

Comment: Passing to dimension $2$ makes the operations of union and intersection much more complicated, if we could describe open sets that would be too convenient to be true. @Jakobian gives the most important point though :) Also, we lack a complete ordering fitting the topologic properties in dimension 2

Comment: @Jakobian You may want to read my answer.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace You may want to read my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every open set in $\Bbb R^2$ can be written as a union of open balls with rational centers and rational radii $U =\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty B_{r_n}(x_n,y_n)$, so you can map it to $(x_0,y_0,r_0,x_1,y_1,r_1,x_2,y_2,r_2,\ldots)$.

Comment: Yes but we won't get the unicity unfortunately

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace Neither in the case of $\Bbb R$. What's your point?

Comment: In $\mathbb{R}$ you can make it so the open intervals don't overlap, you get an union of intervals $]a_q,b_q[$ with $p<q \implies b_p < a_q$

Comment: Could you demonstrate how $\{(x,y)|y>a\}$ where a is irrational would be expressed in such a way? I could see this being very tedious so don’t feel obligated.

Comment: They're just writing the open sets as unions of countable basis. Sure you can encode every open set this way, though I don't know if that's really what you wanted.

Comment: @MilesGould Take $U = \{(x,y)\mid y>a\}$. For any $(x,y)\in U$ there exists $\epsilon$ such that $B_\epsilon(x,y) \subseteq U$. From the density of $\Bbb Q^2$ is easy to see find a point $(u,v)\in \Bbb Q^2$ close enough to $(x,y)$ and a radius $r\in\Bbb Q$ such that $(x,y)\in B_r(u,v)\subseteq B_\epsilon(x,y)\subseteq U$.

Comment: @jjagmath Okay, makes sense. Thank you, this was very helpful!

Comment: @MilesGould If you find this helpful feel free to accept my answer.

Answer (score -1):

As jjagmath said, since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is separable (by $\mathbb{Q}^2)$, you can express $U$ as a countable union of balls of center and radius that are rational. The only issue is that you will lose the unicity of this union.

In $\mathbb{R}$, if you have an open set $U$, you can find $J \subset \mathbb{Q}$ such that
$$U = \bigsqcup_{q \in J} ]a_q,b_q[$$
With $p<q \implies b_p < a_q$.

This decomposition is unique up to increasing bijection, and the sets $ \{a_q, q \in J\}$ and $ \{b_q, q \in J\}$ are both unique and describe $U$.

You unfortunately can't get this with higher dimensional spaces since the topology doesn't match any complete order. You could get an equivalent by looking to the connected parts of $U$ (which are also path-connected) but this will never be as strong as the property in dimension $1$.